# Django count in template on object attribute

Tags: python, django

Here is a way to count objects in the django template:

```
{{ items|count }}
```

Is there a way to count objects with a certain boolean field attribute? Such as:

```
{{ items.boolean_field|count }} # sum([item.boolean_field for item in items])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/

You can create a filter. Something like:

```
@register.filter
def count_true(value):
    return value.filter(boolean_field=True).count()
```

And in your template:

```
{{ items|count_true }}
```